# Find name of employees hired on different joining date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]I wrote a query to find the employess hired on same date.

this is the query

```
select a.name,b.name,a.joining,b.joining from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] a, 
  [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] b where a.joining = b.joining and a.name>b.name
```

Then a question popped into my mind. How do i find those employess only who were hired on different dates? I tried something like this

```
select a.name,b.name,a.joining,b.joining from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] a, 
  [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] b where a.joining != b.joining and a.name>b.name
```

but then i realized this doesnt make sense . I thought about a sub query but it wont work either because we are selecting from two tables.

So i searched and could not find anything.

So the question is how do we "Find name of employees hired on different joining date?"

[image]

Comment: @vkp i do not need a pair. I need employees with different joining dates.

Comment: @McNets this is not the right query

Comment: @vkp i want just the name once and different joining dates of employees , no name must be repeated

Comment: i have edited my comment , please re read

Comment: @vkp btw isn't <> and != the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN the Employees table with a subquery that counts the joining dates.

```
where j.num = 1
```

returns employees hired on different dates

```
where j.num > 1
```

returns employees hired on same date

```
select e.id, e.name, e.joining
from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] e
     inner join (select joining, count(*) num
                 from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees]
                 group by joining) j
     on j.joining = e.joining
where j.num = 1;

+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |       joining       |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 |  abc | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  2 |  def | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  5 |  mno | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+

+----+------+---------------------+
| id | name |       joining       |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  3 |  ghi | 02.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  4 |  jkl | 03.01.2017 00:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/OOO96554

Comment: is this query i sql server syntax? because it is giving an error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'j'.

Comment: this is what i changed it into according to sql server syntax.

 select id,name,joining from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees]
     inner join (select joining, count(*) num
                 from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees]
                 group by joining) j
     on j.joining = joining
where j.num = 1;

Comment: otherwise it was saying "invalid object name #employees"

Comment: #employees is a temporary table I created in restester.com just to develop the answer. let me edit it to fit with your table

Comment: yep , this one works. i understand the logic. but is there another way. I ask this question because with this approach we can find the employees with same joining just by changing "j.num=2". awesome solution though

Comment: j.num = 2 works if there are only two employees with the same `joining` date, use j.num > 1 to fetch all employees hired on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the names (and not the list of different hiring dates), the following rather simple query should do the job:

```sql
select id, name
from employee
group by id, name
having count(distinct joining) > 1
```

Comment: Hm - maybe I understood your question wrong - you are not looking for records where 'the same person hired more than once', right?

Comment: nope that is not what i was looking for , thanks for the effort anyways

Answer (score 0):

after getting the answer , I have another way to get the same result . Here it is. I Hope its helpful to others and someone might explain which approach is better and in what scenario .

```
select name,joining from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees] where joining not in
(
                 select joining
                 from [SportsStore].[dbo].[Employees]
                 group by joining
                 having count(*)=1
)
```